# Handling optional parameters in Azure function table bindings

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to use a filter on an Azure function to look up a row in a table based on an optional route parameter. If the parameter isn't provided, or doesn't match a row, a default row should be returned. This works if I provide a matching value, or a wrong value, I get a row as I expect. If I provide no value at all, I get the following error:

`Exception while executing function: Functions.link. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

The three key bits (AFAIU) are:

- **httpTrigger route**: `"link/{ref?}"`
- **Table filter**: `"Email eq '{ref}' or Default eq true"`
- **Endpoint URL**: `https://[subdomain].azurewebsites.net/api/link/(ref)`

Is there some way to construct the filter or route so that I get the second clause of the filter when the optional parameter is not provided? Or is there a better way to do this?

My full `function.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "route": "link/{ref?}",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "emailRule",
      "type": "table",
      "take": "1",
      "filter": "Email eq '{ref}' or Default eq true",
      "tableName": "RedirectRules",
      "connection": "TestStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this route `"route": "link/{ref=''}",` this way you dont have null value but always empty string

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you! One thing I'm struggling with is the documentation for this sort of thing in Azure - it seems to miss a lot of detail. Do you have a reference you use for this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#customize-the-http-endpoint it says  see Routing in ASP.NET Core.